# Enable submit if one of checkbox is checked in each group

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I found some threads on stack but they are pretty old and kinda not suitable for me.

So I have two checkbox groups and in them im generating 2 or 3 checkboxes via django, how can I enable my submit when **at least one checkbox is checked in each group.**

this is what i found that was similar to mine problem but it don't work with backend generated checkboxes

```js
function check(element) {
  var cb1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
  var cb2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
  var sub = document.getElementById("submit");
  if (cb1.checked == true  &&  cb2.checked == true)
      sub.disabled = false;
  else
      sub.disabled = true;
  }
```

This is how im generating my checkboxes

```
<div class="xTypeDiv">
  {% for x in xType  %}
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{ x.type }}" name="pType" class="pChecbkox" 
     id='checkbox1' onclick="check();">
  {% endfor  %}
</div>

<div class="yTypeDiv">
  {% for x in yType  %}
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{ x.type }}" name="pType" class="pChecbkox" 
     id='checkbox2' onclick="check();">
  {% endfor  %}
</div>
```

Comment: _"...but it don't work with backend generated checkboxes"_ - Then try to adapt it.

Comment: If I knew how I would

Comment: You don't say *how* your "backend generated checkboxes" are generated.  They *should* have a fixed ID.  You *should* be able to give them a class.  And most definitely, you *should* be able to group each group in a div.  So you don't even want to know what the backend-id/class is, use `$(".group").each((i,e) => $(this).find("input:checkbox").length > 0 ...`

Comment: You have multiple `checkbox1` id. Do not use id in loops. An id must be unique. `.getElementById()` will get the first match only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change checkboxes generation to (using a class instead of an id):

```
<div class="xTypeDiv">
  {% for x in xType  %}
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{ x.type }}" name="pType" class="pChecbkox typeX" 
     onclick="check();">
  {% endfor  %}
</div>

<div class="yTypeDiv">
  {% for x in yType  %}
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{ x.type }}" name="pType" class="pChecbkox typeY" 
     onclick="check();">
  {% endfor  %}
</div>
```

Then you can compare the length of checked ones:

```
function check(element) {
  var cb1_checked = document.querySelectorAll(".pChecbkox.typeX:checked");
  var cb2_checked = document.querySelectorAll(".pChecbkox.typeY:checked");
  
  var sub = document.getElementById("submit");
  
  if (cb1_checked.length >= 1  &&  cb2_checked.length >= 1)
      sub.disabled = false;
  else
      sub.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

And fix `pChecbkox`  to `pCheckbox` maybe... ;)